# Pygame. Get wheel angle in degrees

Tags: pygame, angle

I am using pygame to get input data from my racing wheel. There is a method called `get_axis`, that returns an angle as floating number from -1 to 1 (where -1 corresponds to the maximum left angle of rotation of the wheel, and 1 to the right (not radians)). I would like to get it as angle of rotation in degrees.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 360
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 50
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(x) for x in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]

j = joysticks[0]    
j.init()

pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
wheelRange = ... # need to get range racing wheel

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    i = 0
    print("value: " + str(j.get_axis(i) * wheelRange) + " deg") #print current wheel position

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do you get the [cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) of the angle? Represents the range [-1.0,1.0] to minimum and maximum steering angle?

Comment: I don't know how to get minimum and maximum steering angle

Comment: I can't multiply angle_you_have  on 360, e.t. range may be not equal 360 (Some wheels has range 180 degrees, other 900, some has other range)

Comment: @UhnoSemen Can you post your code so that we can see what going on please

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame
from sys import exit as _exit

#handles events 
def handleEvents(events):
    exitGame = False
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pg_window.close()


def write(display:pygame.display, text:str, pos:tuple, size:int, color:tuple):
    font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), size)
    surf = font.render(f"{text}", True, (color[0], color[1], color[2]))
    display.blit(surf, (pos[0], pos[1]))


class PG_Widnow_UI:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pygame.init()
        self.widht = width
        self.height = height
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

    def update(self):
        pygame.display.flip()

    def clear(self, r, g, b):
        self.window.fill((r, g, b))

    def close(self):
        pygame.quit()
        _exit()


windowWidth = 1000
windowHeight = 50
pg_window = PG_Widnow_UI(windowWidth, windowHeight)

while True:
    pg_window.clear(255, 255, 255)

    events = pygame.event.get()
    handleEvents(events)

    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    one_to_minus_one = (mousePos[0] / (windowWidth/2))-1
    in_degrees = ((one_to_minus_one + 1) * 360)/2

    write(pg_window.window, f"steering wheel: {one_to_minus_one}", (0, 0), 15, (255, 0, 0))
    write(pg_window.window, f"in degrees: {in_degrees}", (0, 20), 15, (255, 0, 0))

    pg_window.update()
```

So to sum up, you can do the conversion as follows

```
in_degrees = ((one_to_minus_one + 1) * 360)/2
```

If steering wheels turn to a total of 900 degrees then you can multiply by 900.

```
in_degrees = ((one_to_minus_one + 1) * 900)/2
```

Comment: Some steering wheels can be rotated by 2.5 turns (it is total of 900 degrees). And I don't know how get limit of turn a steering wheel in my program.

Comment: @UhnoSemen times it by 900 then?